# Spanning Trees of the Complete Bipartite Graph

Tags: graph-theory

A problem appeared in a lecture about spanning trees, but we were told to think about it by ourselves.

> The complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ is the graph with $m + n$ vertices $a_1,\ldots ,a_m$, $b_1,\ldots ,b_n$ such that there is an edge between each $a_i$ and each $b_j$, but not between any two $a$'s or any two $b$'s. How many spanning trees does $K_{m,n}$ have?

Although, I don't know if it will help, I figured out that $$ \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^m deg(a_k) = \sum_{k=1}^n deg(b_k) $$ since any edge connected to an $a$ must be connected also to a $b$. Can anyone give a hint on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s not an easy problem, and I don’t see a way to give a useful hint, either for the result or for its proof. If you’d like to try proving it, the answer is that there are $m^{n-1}n^{m-1}$ spanning trees. The easiest proof that I’ve seen is that of **Theorem** $\bf{1}$ in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9090377T); it is proved by a completely different technique, involving adjacency and incidence matrices, in [this PDF](http://www.austinmohr.com/15spring4980/paper%20final%20draft.pdf).